# Something is eating my SSD

Tags: windows-10, firefox, ssd

I brought a SSD on Jan 2020. SSD's TBW is 80TB. When I use Crystal Disk Info, it showed that I have written 860GB in just 2 months whereas I only use Firefox and don't copy and paste things. Something is eating my SSD. How can I monitor which app is eating my SSD. I have disable System Protection and Virtual Memory. If it is Firefox that is eating my SSD, then what should I do?
I use Windows 10 Home (i3-4150, 8GB DDR3 1333 [4GBx2], Crucial SSD BX500 240GB)

Comment: That's not really much, in the overall scheme of things. My system shows 1.5TB in the past week. The low TBW is likely due to it being a small drive. A lot of your early figure is also going to be done in the initial setup & install. I'm not sure switching essential bits of your OS off is really going to help you.

Comment: Why does this concern you? You are writing around 430 GB/month. At that rate, (80000/430) = 186 months or *15 years* of usage. That is hardly "eating up" your SSD.